# Can't display converted JSONObject in EditText

Tags: java, android

I am trying to display a JSONObject that I have converted to string in an EditText field in my android app. When I run the app it loads without error but my EditText field is empty. I also tried to do System.out.println(name); but nothing printed to the console so my best guess is nothing is actually stored there and I am not sure why.
Here is my main file

```
package com.apitest.rottentomatoestest;

import android.os.Bundle;    
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;    
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;    
import org.json.*;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;    
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import java.util.logging.*;

public class Main extends Activity {        

    private static String url = "http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies/770672123/cast.json?apikey=3p9ehnhzbxwpd6mk8fnncf67";

    private static final String TAG_CAST = "cast";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_CHARACTERS = "characters";

    EditText display;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        try
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.mainlayout);
            JSONArray cast = null; 
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
            JSONObject jSon = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);              
            display = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.display);            

            try
            {
                cast = jSon.getJSONArray(TAG_CAST);                 
                for(int i=0; i < cast.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject c = cast.getJSONObject(i);                       
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);                        
                    display.setText(name); 
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("ERROR", "ERROR IN CODE" + e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mainlayout, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

This is my JSONParser class

```
package com.apitest.rottentomatoestest;

import java.io.*;
import org.apache.http.*;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.*;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream inputStream = null;
    static JSONObject jObject = null;
    static String jSon = "";

    public JSONParser() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url){

        //Make HTTP Request
        try {
            //defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            inputStream = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
            }
            inputStream.close();
            jSon = stringBuilder.toString();
        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }
        //try to parse the string to JSON Object
        try {
            jObject = new JSONObject(jSon);
        } catch (JSONException e){
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
        //return JSON String
        return jObject;
    }    
}
```

Comment: did u check it printing the response from the server? make sure that you are getting a valid response from server

Comment: actually the given url returns the json `{"error":"Not Authorized"}` is that the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 cast = jSon.getJSONArray(TAG_CAST);

  for(int i=0; i < cast.length(); i++){
       JSONObject c = cast.getJSONObject(i);

        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

        display.setText(name);
}
```

you'd better check the last value of `name`

Comment: I tried checking the last value of name via System.out.println(name) and that doesn't print anything to the console. Is there another way I can check for the value? In the LogCat I am getting a NullPointerException Error and an Error Parsing data that reads end of input at character 0 of. There is nothing after of. How do I check if im getting a response from the server?

Comment: can you paste the `json` string value you get in class `JSONParser `? the given url return `{"error":"Not Authorized"}`

Comment: the following url works for me: http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies/770672123/cast.json?apikey=3p9ehnhzbxwpbd6mk8fncf67 when I enter that in my browser it loads fine.

Comment: i have checked your code and get the value. check the `httpClient.execute(httpPost)`, is there throw exception `unknownhostexception`? maybe you forget the permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Comment: I did have a unknownhostexception that I caught last night. I gave the app permission and then It started throwing the following error. Error Parsing data JSONException: Value <h1>596 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObejct. Error in Code NullPointerException.

Comment: In an effort to try to figure out what is going on I replaced the json string in my code with a snippet of the json I am trying to access from the rotten tomatoes api. Instead of jSon = stringBuilder.toString I have jSon = jSon = "{\"cast\":\"name\":\"Snoop Dog\"}"; I am now getting Unterminated object error at character 15. I searched for the error and I found some information that said fix it by using escaped quotes but I have  done that and the error still persists. Any ideas?

Comment: I changed my hardcoded to string to jSon = "{{\"cast:\"}:{\"name\":\"Snoop Dog\"}}"; and I get this error now: JSONException: expected ':' after cast at character 10 of {{\"cast:\"}:{\"name\":\"Snoop Dog\"}}. I added another : just to see what would happen after cast: and the error just moves to character 11. Anybody know whats going on here?

Comment: I figured out the correct way to hard code it thanks. It was like this {\"cast\":[{\"id\":\"162661723\",\"name\":\"Snoop Dogg\"}]}.